# Вывести форму из модуля в шаблон

Tags: drupal

Как вывести форму из модуля в шаблон?

Пытаюсь выводить блок, в котором лежит форма:

```
$module = 'crm_status'; // Системное имя модуля
$delta = 1; // Идентификатор блока в модуле
$block = module_invoke($module, 'crm_modules_block_view', $delta);
print $block['content'];
```

Но это не работает. В итоге у меня переменная `block = NULL`.

Почему так?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так нужно выводить контент блока.

```
$block = module_invoke('crm_status', 'block_view', '1');
print render($block['content']);
```

Вот это функция с ядра друпал

```
function module_invoke($module, $hook) {
  $args = func_get_args();
  // Remove $module and $hook from the arguments.
  unset($args[0], $args[1]);
  if (module_hook($module, $hook)) {
    return call_user_func_array($module . '_' . $hook, $args);
  }
}
```

и как можно понять при вызове

```
module_invoke('crm_status', 'block_view', '1')
```

произойдет просто вызов

```
crm_status_block_view(1);
```

Почему так произойдет почитать можно здесь [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Кстати как можете заметить никто не мешает вам передавать и 4 параметра

```
module_invoke('crm_status', 'block_view', '1', 'custom_param')
```

И вот этот 4 парaметр можно принимать в хуке

```
crm_status_block_view($delta, $param){
  // your code
}
```

Когда что нибудь используете смотрите внутрь, обычно там все очень просто.